# VBscript No output attempting query AD users last 30 days

Tags: excel, vbscript, vb6, vba

I had a working query but it was grabbing all users in AD and I am attempting to narrow this down to the last 90 days. The problem is that I no longer have any outputs even though the query does run. I know that my math is wrong and does not take off 90 days. Can anyone offer assistance with this?

```
        Dim currentDate
    currentDate = DateDiff("s", CDate("1/1/1970"), Now()) * 1000#
    currentDate = currentDate - 7776000000# 'Subtracts 90 days
'Does the query
    objCommand.CommandText = _
    "<LDAP://" & strDN & ">;" & _
    "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(lastLogonTimestamp<=" & currentDate & "));" & _
    "adspath,distinguishedname,sAMAccountName,lastLogonTimestamp,DisplayName,WhenCreated,userAccountControl;subtree"
'Output the query info
    Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
    rngOut.CurrentRegion.Offset(2).ClearContents
    While Not objRecordSet.EOF
        rngOut.value = objRecordSet.Fields("DisplayName").value
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(0, 1)
        rngOut.value = objRecordSet.Fields("sAMAccountName").value
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(0, 1)
        rngOut.value = objRecordSet.Fields("WhenCreated").value
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(0, 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objDate = objRecordSet.Fields("lastLogonTimestamp").value
        If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            dtmDate = ""
        Else
            On Error GoTo 0
            lngHigh = objDate.HighPart
            lngLow = objDate.LowPart
            If (lngLow < 0) Then
                lngHigh = lngHigh + 1
            End If
            If (lngHigh = 0) And (lngLow = 0) Then
                dtmDate = ""
            Else
                dtmDate = #1/1/1601# + (((lngHigh * (2 ^ 32)) _
                    + lngLow) / 600000000) / 1440
            End If
        End If
        rngOut.value = dtmDate
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(0, 1)
        rngOut.value = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").value
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(0, 1)
        Set Uservar = objRecordSet.Fields("userAccountControl")
        If Uservar And 2 Then
            rngOut.value = "Disabled"
            rngOut.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
            rngOut.value = "Enabled"
            rngOut.Font.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(1, -5)
        objRecordSet.MoveNext
    Wend
```

I have this working but only when I change `(lastLogonTimestamp<=" & currentDate & "));` to `(lastLogon<=" & currentDate & "));` and for what I am wanting this does not display the correct user base. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I recommend you to use [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595(v=vs.84).aspx) for date calculations.

Comment: @PatricK Active Directory stores dates in a different format, so the built-in tools for date calculations are of limited use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [VBScript tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info) VBScript doesn't expand variables inside strings, so you need to change this:

```
objCommand.CommandText = _
  "<LDAP://" & strDN & ">;" & _
  "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(lastLogonTimestamp>=currentDate));" & _
  "adspath,distinguishedname,sAMAccountName,lastLogon,DisplayName,WhenCreated,userAccountControl;subtree"
```

into this:

```
objCommand.CommandText = _
  "<LDAP://" & strDN & ">;" & _
  "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(lastLogonTimestamp>=" & currentDate & "));" & _
  "adspath,distinguishedname,sAMAccountName,lastLogon,DisplayName,WhenCreated,userAccountControl;subtree"
```

Also, I'd recommend calculating currentDate as a normal `Date` value, e.g. like this:

```
maxAge = 30 'days
currentDate = Now - maxAge
```

or like this:

```
maxAge = 30 'days
currentDate = DateAdd("d", -maxAge, Now)
```

and then convert it to an integer8 value using [this code](http://www.rlmueller.net/Programs/DateToInteger8.txt) from Richard L. Mueller:

```
Function DateToInt8(d)
  biasKey  = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").RegRead("HKLM\System" & _
    "\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias")
  If (UCase(TypeName(biasKey)) = "LONG") Then
    bias = biasKey
  ElseIf (UCase(TypeName(biasKey)) = "VARIANT()") Then
    bias = 0
    For k = 0 To UBound(biasKey)
      bias = bias + (biasKey(k) * 256^k)
    Next
  End If

  DateToInt8 = CStr(DateDiff("s", #1/1/1601#, DateAdd("n", bias, d))) & "0000000"
End Function

...

objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://" & strDN & ">;" & _
  "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(lastLogonTimestamp>=" & _
  DateToInt8(currentDate) & "));adspath,distinguishedname,sAMAccountName," & _
  "lastLogon,DisplayName,WhenCreated,userAccountControl;subtree"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code. I have updated my code but when I run it there are no outputs. I believe this is because of the math is wrong and it is trying to find users in the future instead of 30 days ago.

Comment: I have it working, but it only works when I change lastLogonTimestamp<=" & currentDate & ")) to lastLogon<=" & currentDate & "))

Which does not help for what I am doing. I have updated my code to the newest version I am using.